# ObjectDataSourceControl unable to find Type in imported namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, namespaces, objectdatasource

I have an aspx page in a ASP.NET 2.0 application using several ObjectDataSources.
They are all bound to the same class like so:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="TitleDataSource" runat="server" OnSelecting="TitleDataSource_Selecting" SelectMethod="GetTitle" TypeName="DropDownDataSource"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This was working fine.  Then I made two changes

1. Moved the `DropDownDataSource` from the `app_code` directory to a separate assembly
2. changed the namespace of the class was `com.companyname.ie`,  now `com.companyname.ie.appname`

Now I get a "Type Specified in TypeName of 'TitleDataSource' could not be found" error message when I hit the page.

I can fix this by specifying the fully qualified name of the class in `TypeName`. But adding an  `<% @import`  directive with the same namespace does not resolve the error.

I've also tried moving my code back into `app_code` to no avail.

Intellisense picks up the Type without me specifying the namespace.

Its not a massive problem, but its very annoying. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the fully qualified name is correct.  Otherwise the runtime will only look in the current assembly.

Comment: Jakob, thanks for the reply but as noted in my question: I've tried moving my code back into app_code (where it was working previously)and it still does not pick up the unqualified name . I believe I've eliminated the Assembly as a possible source of the problem. Unless there is some caching?

Comment: That is probably because you changed the namespace as well so it is different from the default namespace of your web site.  You may want to try using the designer for the ObjectDataSource (by clicking the small arrow besides the ObjectDataSource in the designer).

Comment: I believe the Wizard will show you a list of available types.

Comment: Jakob,  tried the wizard. sure enough its only showing the fully qualified name. Guess thats what I'll have to use then. Thanks.